# How to compute witness for Merkle tree proof using Zokrates?

Tags: solidity, zero-knowledge, merkle, zokrates

I am trying to learn how Zero Knowledge proof for Merkle tree verification work. Therefore I am using this example from Zokrates:

```
import "hashes/pedersen/512bit" as hash;
import "hashes/utils/256bitsDirectionHelper" as multiplex;

const u32 DEPTH = 3;


def main(u32[8] root, private u32[8] leaf, private bool[DEPTH] directionSelector,     private u32[DEPTH][8] path) -> bool {
// Start from the leaf
u32[8] mut digest = leaf;

// Loop up the tree
for u32 i in 0..DEPTH {
    u32[16] preimage = multiplex(directionSelector[i], digest, path[i]);
    digest = hash(preimage);
}

return digest == root;
}
```

Can you help me with an example how to fill out those fields when I compile the program:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the multiplex() function is to create a preimage which is used as an input to the hash function. This preimage is formed by combining the two inputs, the digest of the current node in the Merkle tree and the direction selector which determines which of the two nodes in the current tree level should be chosen as the next node in the Merkle tree. The preimage is then hashed with the hash function to produce the digest of the next node in the Merkle tree. This process is repeated until the root of the Merkle tree is reached.

The following code example shows how to compute a witness for a Merkle tree proof using Zokrates. The code takes a root of a Merkle tree, a leaf and a path of nodes as inputs, and returns a boolean value representing whether the leaf is included in the tree or not.

```
def main(u32[8] root, private u32[8] leaf, private u32[DEPTH][8] path) -> bool {
// Start from the leaf
u32[8] mut digest = leaf;

// Loop up the tree
for u32 i in 0..DEPTH {
    u32[16] preimage = multiplex(digest, path[i]);
    digest = hash(preimage);
}

return digest == root;
}
```

The witness for this Merkle tree proof would consist of the leaf, the direction selector and the path. The witness would need to be provided as an input to the Zokrates program in order to verify the proof.

Comment: Thank you but can you show me an example of input parameters in order to execute this function ?